# What to log to debug Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]?

Tags: node.js, express

In an Express controller function, I am running into to this error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]`. This occurs when I call `res.json()` if headers have already been set on the `res` object. However, I don't see place in my function (or middleware) where headers could be set prior to my calling `res.json()`.

To debug the cause of this error, I thought I could add some logging. Prior to calling `res.json`, I could check if headers had been set and, if so, log some information about who set them.

```
async function get(req, res) {

  ... 

  if (res._header) {
    logger.debug(...);
  }

  res.json(...);
```

Unfortunately, I don't see anything useful in the `res` object to log, any message that would indicate why/how the headers were set (or who set them). Any suggestions for what I could log to debug this issue? Or other debugging suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to include the full get code function

Comment: The error could possible be because you are returning multiple responses to same request, In any case it would be really helpful for other to provide a solution if you add the relevant code where error occurs along the express api that returns the response

Comment: I don't think there is any one specific thing you can log that will tell you the answer. For example if your get function above is called more than once then you will get that error. It's not possible to see what is going on with out seeing all of your code. If you provide a minimal reproducible example that would help us help you.

Comment: Can you please paste the code for the `get` method. You may be trying to `res.send` and then trying to `res.json`. It will be helpful if you can paste your code here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch `res.header` `res.send` `res.set` to log the stack trace for you. For example this is my main application.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const someGoody = require('./stupid-blackbox');

/** patch the res **/
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const _header = res.header.bind(res); // .header and .set is an alias pair
  const _send = res.send.bind(res);

  res.header = res.set = (field, val) => {
    console.trace('.header/.set called', field, val);
    console.log('-----');
    return _header(field, val);
  }

  res.send = (body) => {
    console.trace('.send called', body);
    console.log('-----');
    return _send(body);
  }

  next();
})

// some innocent looking middleware
app.use(someGoody);

// my main routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.json({url: req.url});
})

app.listen(3000);
```

And for `stupid-blackbox.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('X-Crash-You', '1').send(':)');
  next();
})

module.exports = router;
```

When ran, you will get this in the log:

```
Trace: .header/.set called X-Crash-You 1
    at ServerResponse.res.header.res.set (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\index.js:11:13)
    at router.use (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\stupid-blackbox.js:6:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
-----
Trace: .send called :)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\index.js:17:13)
    at router.use (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\stupid-blackbox.js:6:36)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eric_\Desktop\initial\play\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

On the second line of each stack trace you can see the stupid-blackbox.js.

On a side note, `res.json` will not result in error if only `res.header` or `res.set` is called, the error is headers has been *sent* so that means somewhere in the code, `res.send` is called causing headers to be *sent* before your actual code.

Comment: thanks. This looks like it will help me track down the unexpected `res.send`